# Get valid keys/address with ed25519

Tags: eztz, cryptography

I read [this](http://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/21/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-signing-operations/) great post on tz1 keys with `ed25519`. I also saw that the [eztz](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz) lib doesn't support ed25519 keys.

So I'm trying to understand briefly what is considered a valid procedure to get keys/address. Basically I'm trying to achieve in JS what the `tezos-client` does in that article above using [elliptic ed25519](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic).

```
Hash: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
Public Key: edpkuBknW28nW72KG6RoHtYW7p12T6GKc7nAbwYX5m8Wd9sDVC9yav
Secret Key: edsk3gUfUPyBSfrS9CCgmCiQsTCHGkviBDusMxDJstFtojtc1zcpsh
```

Any JS snippet available around?

Comment: I think you are confused -- eztz does support ed25519. It's not clear what you want -to do. Generate new keys?

Comment: before i flag this question for moderation, can you first please edit it as its unclear what you are asking. And as previous comment states, eztz definitely supports ed25519 as it's the default. Follow the eztz link you listed, and then go to the documentation and you will see the generateKeys call.

Comment: I wanna generate keys that long! Right now eztz will generate me 98 chars length private keys. There's not trace of ed25519 in https://github.com/TezTech/eztz - are you referring to libsodium?

Comment: I see. Yes, eztz uses sodium through some wrapper and does support ed25519/tz1. There are two forms of ed25519 secret keys accepted by the tezos programs -- long (the full secret key) and short (the "seed", which is what the tezos programs show you by default). eztz is producing the long form. Both should work fine. Maybe update the question to make it clear that this is what you're asking about?